# Spring Boot with Kubernetes Java Client API - Edit Namespace

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-java-client

I try to implement a sample example of Kubernetes Java Client Api in Spring Boot example. I already handled with creating , deleting and getting namespace but I couldn't handle with updating namespace by name in my Spring Boot example.

Here is the EditNamespaceRequest shown below

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class EditNamespaceRequest {
    private String name;
}
```

Here is the updateNamespace method of my Service

```java
public V1Namespace updateNamespace(String currentName, EditNamespaceRequest editNamespaceRequest) throws ApiException {

try {
            // Retrieve the existing namespace
            V1Namespace existingNamespace = coreV1Api.readNamespace(currentName, null);

            // Update the existing namespace with the new values
            existingNamespace.metadata(new V1ObjectMeta().name(editNamespaceRequest.getName()));

            // Perform the update
            coreV1Api.replaceNamespace(currentName, existingNamespace, null, null, null,null);

            return existingNamespace;
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Handle API exception (e.g., namespace not found, permission issues, etc.)
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to update namespace: " + e.getResponseBody(), e);
        }

    }
```

I have a problem to update Namespace by name through Kubernetes Java Client API.

this error message is shown below when I run

```
 {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"the name of the object (namespace-update) does not match the name on the URL (namespace-new)","reason":"BadRequest","code":400}
```

How can I fix it?

I try to implement a sample example of Kubernetes Java Client Api in Spring Boot example. I already handled with creating , deleting and getting namespace but I couldn't handle with updating namespace by name in my Spring Boot example. How can I fix it?

Comment: Is the field you are trying to change is `spec.name` ?

Comment: @SaifeddineRajhi its name is defined at the point of  `metadata.name`. I hope you can help me.

Comment: name is immutable field in namespace

Comment: How can I change namespace by name? @SaifeddineRajhi

Comment: I mean the filed you want to change in the namespace is its **name** ? if yes then that is not possible because name is an  immutable field in namespace

Comment: @SaifeddineRajhi `replaceNamespace` method is already defined. How can I change the namespace by name?

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by change .. that was my initial question what are you trying to change or replace in the namespace exactly

Comment: I supposed that replaceNamespace  can be handled with updating namespace by name. I asked you about it.

Comment: Yes but what do you try to update which field

Comment: @SaifeddineRajhi `name` field

Comment: Then that is not possible because you cannot change name of namespace after creation

Comment: @SaifeddineRajhi Which fields cannot I update ?

Comment: `name` field  is immutable it cannot be changed

Comment: @SaifeddineRajhi I can update any field except for `name`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you can try to change the `labels` or `annotations` for example .. test it and let me know

Comment: @SaifeddineRajhi Can you share the code for updating labels or annotations with me if possible?

Comment: I am not good at java but try `patchNamespace` function instead of `replaceNamespace`

Comment: @SaifeddineRajhi If not, How can I do that? What I'm coming in my mind is to move all deployments of defined namespace to another one with deployments. Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do here is basiaclly to update the name of the K8S namespace, [which is impossible](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/qkxsfb/how_to_rename_namespace/). Thus the cluster does not allow you to modify the namespace and returns 400.

Comment: If not, How can I do that? What I'm coming in my mind is to move all deployments of defined namespace to another one with deployments. Is it right?

Comment: @jacksondel If you need to rename a deployment, you have only one option- just re-create it with a different name. That involves the recreation of the resources in it of course as you said - moving all resources to new namespace. Check please this K8S issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43867
If I answered your question, please, upvote and accept it :)

Comment: Can I only move Deployment with existing name to deployment with new namespace? Is it right? What about pods, replicasets?

Comment: @jacksondel Deployment is a ReplicaSet with history of it's updates essentially. And Replicaset is a collection of pods. If I understand you correctly, then If you'll move a deployment, then underlying ReplicaSet and pods would migrate as well. This is already another issue, please accept the answer and upvote it to close this question. If you have anything else - ask new question and I'll answer :)

Comment: Which process should I implement to change namaspace?